# How Do I Get an Object to Listen For its Property's Event?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, event-handling

I have an object of type `SomeObject`, with an event `StatusChanged`.

I have a property in `SomeObject` of type `Status` also with an event `StatusChanged`.

Within a private function in `SomeObject`, I would like to run some logic (including firing the `StatusChanged` event) in the event that `Status` has fired *its* `StatusChanged` event. I have been away from events for a while so it's a bit cloudy to me. How do I do this?

I'm writing in ASP.NET/VB.NET

Thanks :)

**EDIT** Ok, in the event that I can't do the above, how would I get the outer object (`SomeObject`) to fire its `StatusChanged` event when the inner object (`Status`) fires *its* `StatusChanged` event?

Comment: You need to specify the relationship between these objects. Does `SomeObject` have a member whose type is `Status`? Is that the object whose `StatusChanged` event you care about?

Comment: @john - yes, you are correct. There is a property of type `Status` in `SomeObject`... sorry for not being clear!

Answer (score 1):

Events don't work that way. You can't perform logic based on whether an event *has been fired*. You can only write logic that takes place *when* an event is fired.

---

Ok, here's an attempt. It's been a while since I've done this in VB.NET, though:

```
Public Enum CurrentStatus
    Good
    Bad
End Enum

Public Class StatusEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs
    Private _currentStatus As CurrentStatus

    Public Property CurrentStatus() As CurrentStatus
        Get
            Return _currentStatus
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As CurrentStatus)
            _currentStatus = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class StatusClass
    Public Event StatusChanged As EventHandler(Of StatusEventArgs)

    Protected Overridable Sub OnStatusChanged(ByVal newStatus As CurrentStatus)
        Dim s As New StatusEventArgs()
        s.CurrentStatus = newStatus
        RaiseEvent StatusChanged(Me, s)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class SomeClass
    Private _status As StatusClass
    Public Event StatusChanged As EventHandler(Of StatusEventArgs)

    Protected Overridable Sub OnStatusChanged(ByVal newStatus As CurrentStatus)
        Dim s As New StatusEventArgs()
        s.CurrentStatus = newStatus
        RaiseEvent StatusChanged(Me, s)
    End Sub

    Public Property Status() As StatusClass
        Get
            Return _status
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As StatusClass)
            If Not _status Is Nothing Then
                RemoveHandler _status.StatusChanged, AddressOf StatusHandler
            End If

            _status = value

            If Not _status Is Nothing Then
                AddHandler _status.StatusChanged, AddressOf StatusHandler
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub StatusHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As StatusEventArgs)
        OnStatusChanged(e.CurrentStatus)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: bah. i suck at events. i was afraid of this answer.

Comment: ok then, how do i get the outer object to fire its `StatusChanged` event when the inner object's `StatusChanged` event is fired?